# Do Americans use the expression "it looks common"? If so, what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Since the US is not based on a class system, is this expression used at all or does it belong to the peculiarities of the British language?

```
common adjective (LOW CLASS) 
disapproving
typical of a low social class: 
My mum thinks dyed blonde hair is a bit common.
```

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/common)

Comment: Just Brits, I am positive. Americans do say, I think, that some people are 'trailer trash'. Many people in both societies strongly disapprove of such classist language.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, **you** may be positive, but **I** am American :-)

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum +1 for that!

Comment: [Common people (like you)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuTMWgOduFM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US one does hear things like *Don’t act that way, it’s so common*, but—dare I say it?—not all that commonly. The disparaging sense of *common* is a good deal less frequent over here than the other senses are. Instead, *common* is generally used to mean typical or everyday.

And of course there’s also the sense of shared, as in *common denominator* or the onetime *Common Market*, if you’re old enough to remember that. (Although that term was of course applicable only to the context of the UK, no American would hear in it a different sense of *common*.)

In general, for an American to hear the disparaging sense requires non-negligible hints from context. We do use the term *common criminal*, but to my ear it sounds more as though it means *run-of-the-mill criminal*. If I hear the disparaging *common* in *She’s nothing but a common tramp*, that likely reflects the sexist practice of slandering women as being “loose” (whereas men can be merely rakish). But I suppose that double standard transcends all linguistic boundaries.

One word that does feel very much at home here in the US, complete with its classist connotation, is *lowdown*. But one would almost never use it in Standard American English without irony, as in *He ain’t nothin’ but a lowdown cattle-rustlin’ varmint!”

Comment: It's in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/common) with the senses unrefined and second-rate but the examples are British, certainly suggesting it's rarer in the US.

Comment: My mother was fond of saying that this or that thing or person was 'common'. Off the top of my head, peroxide blondes, talking or walking about with a cigarette in your mouth, saying 'ain't', not washing empty milk bottles before putting them out.